# How to offset / add margin to tiled overlay image in ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to offset my tiled overlay image 50px vertically from the North side of the background image.

As far as I could see is that

`composite <overlay> <background> -tile -geometry +0+50 -gravity North <tiled_image>`

does not really work. Because when `-tile` option is used, it ignores `-geometry` and `-gravity` option. It kinda make senses but well wondering if there is any way to achieve the desired effect.

Much thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may come up with something more elegant, but for the moment, I have got this. Start with a black background image and a red-yellow gradient overlay image:

```
# Make background
convert -size 1000x1000 xc:black background.jpg
```

[image]

```
# Make overlay
convert -size 80x80 gradient:red-yellow overlay.jpg
```

Now do some magic!

```
convert background.jpg                                \
   \( +clone -chop x50 -fill none -colorize 100%      \
      -tile overlay.jpg -draw "color 0,0 reset"  \)   \
   -gravity south -composite tile.jpg
```

[image]

Essentially, I clone the image inside the parentheses and chop the top 50 pixels off, then I blank the canvas, tile over the top of it and composite it back on top of the original aligned with the bottom. The `-fill none -colorize 100%` is probably unnecessary unless your tile is partially transparent.

Comment: though not very elegant, it does the job fine. Thanks much